# Using only the first three letters of the English alphabet

Tags: word, language

Find an English word which is three letters long beginning with t using only the first three letters of the English alphabet

Now do the same using the same three letters but for a French word You may add an accent

Hint for those who are stuck

> punctuation

Once you have solved it please include in the answer how the hint worked

Comment: Wait, punctuation? Punctuation characters are not **letters**. What?

Comment: Perhaps adding some choice punctuation changes the meaning of a sentence?

Comment: He wants a **word** three **letters** long, and no other thing, including punctuation.

Comment: @Okx but you do realize that punctuation is used in the formation of words, do you not

Comment: I am quite new to Puzzling, so yes — please do feel free to add/suggest any tags which you feel to be appropriate.

Comment: OH MY GOD I did not realize this puzzle was created by my alter ego

Comment: Haha — Maybe I should be Question Answerer then :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> THE uses the first three letters of "the English alphabet"
> Thé is a french word, with an accent.

Punctuation would have helped in the clue

> if you had use quotes around "the English alphabet"

Comment: Nicely done. I will make a harder question next :)

Comment: Feel like an obligatory https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: To be precise, I missed out all of the punctuation in the question to attempt to confuse.

Comment: At least this one works in verbal form.  The GRY one also requires broken or awkward phrasing.